# I can push with Git Bash, but I cannot with MINGW

Tags: windows, git, mingw

I use MINGW32 under Windows 7 and I want to configure Git for that.
I know that there is the Git bash but I would like to use my MINGW32 installation

Right now my problem is that I cannot push my code.
After issuing "git push origin master" it simply stops waiting for something.
Probably is an ssh configuration issue (maybe is not finding the ssh agent?), but I can't figure out what it is.
This is what I see

```
$ git push origin master --verbose
Pushing to git@github.com:mottalrd/myprj.git
```

Then nothing happens

Notice that the ssh connection works, in fact if I issue ssh -T git@github.com I get this

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Enter passphrase for key '/home/motta/.ssh/id_dsa':
Hi mottalrd! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Thank you

Comment: How long have you waited for it to finish? Maybe the issue is, it's really, really slow (which can happen).

Comment: minutes. This is not the problem also because on the other side the git bash commits immediately and it is based on MINGW

Comment: Do you know where I could get a log of what's going on? Using the verbose option of git push do not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this is a very well know problem and that it is related with mintty, which I had installed on top of MINGW

It is called the pty problem. You can browser the MINGW community to find people having this exact problem. I switched to console2 that is a replacement to mintty. This solved my problem